# git fatal: pathspec 'TTSConsole.java' did not match any files while adding file which has change

Tags: git

I changed some files, I when I say `git status` it shows me all the files which has changes, but when I add them as `git add myFile.java` it says `fatal: pathspec 'myFile.java' did not match any files`

Comment: You should give full path to ur file

Comment: Provide the complete command the brings this error.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a spelling/case sensitive problem. Try copying and pasting the path from git status, or:

To add all changed files

```
git add -u
```

To add all files

```
git add .
```